# Adding slides to beginning of slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Does anyone know a jQuery slider that has solid callback support, and can allow me to add a slide to the beginning of a slideshow while a user is on the page without disrupting the slide the user is on? wootheme's flexslider has addSlide() but it handles this very poorly if you try to add something to the beginning (position 0) Swiper http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/ has a prepend() function, but as you can see in their demo, whenever you prepend it jumps the current slide to the one before.

I need to add content to the beginning of a slider with touch functionality like these two, but I need that to be invisibly added without messing up or jumping around the current slider position. Can anyone suggest one that they like? Obviously I prefer one that is free and allows me to use multiple places like a Creative Commons license.

Answer (score 1):

For slideshows, I really recommend jQuery cycle plugin.

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Comment: there seems to be a lot of stress on many different kinds of animations, do you have any idea if this slider can achieve the functionality I am looking for, or if it supports adding/subtracting slides after the page has loaded?

Comment: I know you can dynamically add slides as shown here: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/add.html

Also, since the slides are based on the DOM, you could just use jQuery's `prepend` function to place the image at the beginning of the slideshow container

Comment: Ok, thanks for finding that. Unfortunately they only give examples of adding slides to the end of the row, I'll take some time to test this and see if I can add slides to the beginning without the weird glitchy behavior that every other slider suffers from.

The reason I can't simply prepend items on the other sliders is that the slider has an idea of what position the slide is differently from the DOM, and it ignores the actual position of the <li> tag relative to the others.

Comment: Nope! It forces the image to append to the end, since you HAVE to add it with their addSlide function.